# dotnet new angular FileNotFoundException with framework assembly

Tags: .net, angularjs, visual-studio

I ran these two commands to create a .Net Core 1.1 project with support for Angular:

dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*

dotnet new angular

Let's call this the "created project".

Now I want to use some pre-existing .Net 4.0 assemblies in the WebAPI controller of the created project. I referenced those assemblies in both the created project and in a new project, and I also referenced in the new project in the created project.

The solution builds fine. However, at runtime I get a "FileNotFoundException" when I invoke a method on an object in the referenced project, which in turn uses a class (let's call it "DataRetriever") from one of the pre-existing assemblies.

I can see the referenced assemblies in the bin folder of the created project, so I don't understand the exception.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

OK, further research suggests that what I want to do really cannot be done. For an explanation, see: [Reference .NET 4.5 dll in .NET Core 1.1 csproj?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349605/reference-net-4-5-dll-in-net-core-1-1-csproj)

The project created by the command lines has no option to target a framework - it's only .Net Core 1.1 or 1.0.

So, what I think I will need to do is create a new Web API project, outside of the .Net Core project. If the new project is not .Net Core, but targets a full framework like .Net 4.5, then I will be able to call into that Web API and use existing .dll's there, returning json for consumption by my front end.

So, the project created by the command lines will really just be for the front end only.